# Smash up Sprout and Weed eater

Tags: smash-up

Played special ability of Sprout (On your turn you may search a minion of power 3 or less on your deck and play it here as an extra minion).

So I choose Weed eater she has 5 power but has an ability ( The turn you played has -2 power ).

Can I choose her?

Or should I look for a specific 3 or less power from my deck?

Answer (score 1):

Weed Eater: This cannot be played to replace a
Sprout, since it does not lower its power until it is
in play. Its power goes back up to 5 after the end
of the turn in which it is played.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way - it's power 5 while it's in your deck, so it can't be pulled out by Sprout (it could by the citzien card in the superhero faction), once it's played, then it goes down to 3.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).